# How do we show that photons generated by a constant electric current are distributed according to a Poisson distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-optics

I saw the answer sometimes ago in a book "Quantum Electronics" or similar title. I don't remember the author since I lost the book. The book sets ( I believe so ) a constant electric current $I$ in a cable along the $z$ axis. Then, after a long ( but not straightforward ) calculation it arrives to the result I mentioned above.

Edit: A possible analogous calculation that OP refered to, Klein-Gordon particles generated by a classical source: [problem 4.1](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jbourj/peskin/4-1.pdf)  in these notes(In fact a solution manual to Peskin and Schroeder). If this is not what OP refered to, please delete it.

Comment: There is a not so clear discussion in "Fundamentals of Quantum Optics, J. R. Klauder and E. C. G. Sudarshan, Section ${\bf\mbox{7-4 B}}$, pag. 141. W. A. BENJAMIN, INC 1968".

Comment: +1, I've only seen a perturbative calculation finally giving a poisson distribution, I'd like to see if there is a more insightful approach.

Comment: what sort of a device gives the photons? a dc current incandescent lamp? Is this connected with Shot noise?

Comment: @JiaYiyang Thanks. Your addenda is quite right and it adds more insight into my question.